# Observer OnError delegate is not called multiple times

Tags: .net-core, observable, system.reactive

Hello i am trying to understand why the `OnError` does not get called everytime by the `Observer`.
When trying to debug the `OnError` called inside my `IOBservable` implementation , the debugger passes by.

**Observable** implementation

```
public class Reactive:IStorage,IObservable<SquareResult>
        {
            private object @lock = new object();
            private List<IObserver<SquareResult>> observers = new List<IObserver<SquareResult>>();


            public static Reactive Create()
            {
                return new Reactive();
            }

            public void Enqueue(SquareResult square)
            {
                lock (@lock)
                {
                    foreach (var item in observers)
                    {
                        if (square.Result < 0)
                        {
                            item.OnError(new InvalidSquareException());
                        }
                        else
                        item.OnNext(square);
                    }
                }
            }
            public void EndStoring()
            {
                this.observers.ForEach(obs => obs.OnCompleted());
            }

            public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<SquareResult> observer)
            {
                if (!this.observers.Contains(observer))
                {
                    this.observers.Add(observer);
                }
                return new Unsubscriber(observer, this.observers);
            }

            public class Unsubscriber : IDisposable
            {
                private List<IObserver<SquareResult>> observers;
                private IObserver<SquareResult> observer;

                public Unsubscriber(IObserver<SquareResult>obs,List<IObserver<SquareResult>>observers)
                {
                    this.observer = obs;
                    this.observers = observers;
                }

                public void Dispose()
                {
                    if (this.observer == null)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    this.observers.Remove(this.observer);
                }
            }
        }
```

The only method that is called by the producer is `Enqueue`.

Then we have a service in which the `consumer` takes data from the `IObservable` and sends it over the socket:

**Consumer**

```
class ProgressService
    {
        private IStorage observable;
        public ProgressService(IStorage storage)
        {
            this.observable = storage;
        }

        public async Task NotifyAsync(WebSocket socket)
        {

            byte[] buffer = ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(1024);
            CancellationTokenSource cancelSignal = new CancellationTokenSource();
            this.observable.Subscribe(async (next) =>
            {

                try
                {
                    ReadOnlyMemory<byte> data = next.Encode();
                    await socket.SendAsync(data, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    if (socket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
                    {

                        await socket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.InternalServerError, "Threw on data receive", CancellationToken.None);
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }, async(ex) =>
            {
                 //!! this delegate does not get called everytime the observable calls OnError(exception)
                await socket.SendAsync($"Exception :{ex.Message}".Encode().ToArray(), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
            }, async () =>
            {
                await socket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "Finished test", CancellationToken.None);
            }, cancelSignal.Token);

            await socket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);
            cancelSignal.Cancel();
        }


    }
```

So what basically happens is if i call from somewhere `myobservable.OnError(new exception())` a couple of times, the callback of the `consumer` is called only once and i do not understand why.

**Example**:

`observable.OnError(new Exception());
 observable.OnError(new Exception());`

**Observer.OnError implmenetation**

```
public void OnError(Exception ex)
{
  Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
 }
```

The above example in my code would print the exception message just once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ['Observable contract'](http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html) allows 0 or more `OnNext` notifications, followed by one `OnCompleted` or one `OnError` notification, which terminate the observable. Once the observable is terminated (by the first `OnError` in your case), no more notifications are emitted, meaning no more delegates are called.

Comment: Oh ok, but is there any way to not terminate the observable if there was one error in the pipeline (`OnNext` was called)  ?

Comment: Sort of not really. There are operators like `Catch` and `Retry` that allow you react to an `OnError` and effectively re-connect. I recommend reading [introtorx.com](http://introtorx.com), specifically [this section](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/11_AdvancedErrorHandling.html#AdvancedErrorHandling) for more info.

Comment: The cleanest way to allow multiple errors is to start with an `IObservable<IObservable<T>>` and perform the following: `source.Select(inner => inner.Materialize()).Merge()`. Then you can deal with the multiple errors.